# other requirements for developer payload in android in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

For some odd reasons, I am unable to get the developerPayload.  I'm using the Dungeons Example.  I have seen this work before, I think the payload string should appear in the Recent Activity.  As far as I know, it should work if I'm using an actual product ID (like, potion_001).  The whole purchasing works very well, but alas, the developerPayload is not there.  I have barely made an edit with the Dungeons sample apart from renaming the package name.  I did try to edit the intent actions, though:

```
    public static final String ACTION_CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION =
        "com.blah.something.dungeons.en.CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION";
    public static final String ACTION_GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION =
        "com.blah.something.dungeons.en.GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION";
    public static final String ACTION_RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS =
        "com.blah.something.dungeons.en.RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS";
```

It still didn't work.  I have been re-reading the in-app billing docs, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something here. Is there something that I may have missed, or misconfigured in the android market options and/or the dungeons sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now.  For some odd reasons, the developerPayload just came back.  There was also someone in the net who had the same problems as I am, and it also happened just last weekend (http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/androidmarket/thread?tid=197b77d86cbb09ff&hl=ja).  It's in japanese, though, but basically he also had problems with developerPayload being null, and then it also came back again a few days later.  I also live in japan, so I guess this might have happened only in our area. I guess it really was true, that transferring payload is quite  a heavy workload for google.

Answer (score 0):

You are not receiving the `developerPayload` in `DEBUG MODE`. You need to sign your application to `RELEASE MODE` to receive `developerPayload`.

Comment: I already exported it with a signed key, then compiled with debug mode turned off when I did this.  Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to purchase any items in the first place.  I'm not sure if that qualifies enough as 'release mode', though.  Is there something more I've missed?